# Convert Power Series to function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I tried to solve the attached Power Series, however I can't get to the right answer.
I wrote down the correct answer at the top-right of the page.

Appreciate your help!

[image: my solution]

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Why not look at $\sum \left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)x^n$? Two series, one very familiar, the other almost as familiar.

**Added**: We have $\sum_1^\infty x^n=\frac{x}{1-x}$.

Also, $-\sum_1^\infty \frac{x^n}{n+1}=\frac{1}{x}\sum_1^\infty -\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}.$

Finally, $\sum_1^\infty -\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}=\ln(1-x)+x$.

Answer (score 0):

@Andre Nicolas

I got something totally differet. Separated as recommended for two series. and got: $\frac{x}{1-x} - \frac{1}{x(1-x)^2}$

Comment: I just saw your post, was not notified. The sum of the first  is what you say it is. The sum of the second is $\frac{1}{x}\sum_1^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$. But $\sum_1^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ is just $-\ln(1-x)$ with one term missing.  Can you finish?

Comment: @AndréNicolas  the same result as I got in the beginning. probably there's a mistake in answers. thanks!